# iphone developer program contract

Tags: iphone

i wanted to enroll to iphone developer program, planning to use my friend credit card, once it is activated , can i give my account information to get money from my paid app ?,

I heard from searching that if individual developer signs program, user name appears in the seller section of the application ?.. is there any way to hide actual name from the seller ? either showing different display name ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own credit card to apply.  Apple has been reported to reject or delay applications where the name on the credit card does not match the name of the applicant.

If you want to use a different name, you should incorporate under the desired name, get your legal corporation papers ready to fax to Apple, and register in the iOS Developer program using that company name.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a friends credit card info for signing up.

As for the rest of the information, You can set that up when you login to iTunes Connect. The company name, or individual name has nothing to do with what credit card was used. The Username does NOT appear anywhere in the app profile.

Answer (score 0):

> The Username does NOT appear anywhere in the app profile.

Username will not be shown on Appstore but in iTunes Store.